# Null trapezoid in d3.js funnel chart

Tags: d3.js, birt

I am trying to get a funnel chart in one of my reports (using BIRT Reporting Tool). I got some code already used for it:  http://smithamilli.com/funnel-charts-in-d3-js/

However, when I try to simulate the same in plain HTML file, I get the following javascript error:

TypeError: trapezoid.node(...) is null

var totalLength = trapezoid.node().getTotalLength();

Is it something I am doing wrong or the included js has got something to do with ?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you're doing and ideally include the code? It looks like you're missing something, but without seeing what you're doing, we can't help you.

Comment: You should create a jsfiddle for this, it will be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an HTML element with the id funnelContainer in your code? The funnel chart doesn’t add HTML elements, but instead selects the element with the id that you’ve chosen to use as a container, so it needs to be there beforehand.